# Showing that an operator is positive

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, and $T$ an operator. The task is to prove that the corresponding self adjoint operator $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & T \\
    T^{*} & 1\\   
    \end{bmatrix}
$ defined on $\mathcal{H}\oplus \mathcal{H}$ is positive (semidefinite) iff $||T||\leq 1$.  My question is whether the usual method in the case of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ where we can find that the eigen values for the matrix     $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & b \\
    b^{*} & 1\\   
    \end{bmatrix}$ are $|b|+1$ and $-|b|+1$, (implying positivity if $|b|\leq 1$) can be adapted to the non commutative setting. In other words, can we find a block form  for the operator as $\begin{bmatrix}
    1+\sqrt{T^*T} & 0 \\
    0 & 1-\sqrt{T^*T}\\   
    \end{bmatrix}$ and obtain the proof in this manner? If this won't work, any hints appreciated

Comment: To know if your method works, we should know a diagonalizing matrix for $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & b \\ b^\star & 1\end{bmatrix}$. If it can be "quantized" (by the substitution $b\mapsto T$) then it should be true that the quantized matrix diagonalizes $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & T \\ T^\star & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I tried that, and I wasn't sure how the "normalization" of the matrix to get a unitary would work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint: $$\begin{pmatrix}I&-T\\0&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I&T\\T^*&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\-T^*&I\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}I-TT^*&0\\T^*&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\-T^*&I\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}I-TT^*&0\\0&I\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I don't think that transformation will preserve the spectrum though, or will it? Will it be true that the spectrum will be the same upto scaling?

Comment: Whoops, sorry I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @KesavKrishnan: Your comment is a rightful objection; the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} I & -T \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}$ is not the inverse of $\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -T^\star & I\end{bmatrix}$. However, since these matrices are one the adjoint of the other, they preserve positivity of the matrix they conjugate. I thought it would be interesting to explicitly add this remark.

Comment: That was my point.  This answer is a hint because the reader needs to fill in missing details.